# Issue in maven release:prepare - svn commit failure

Tags: svn, maven-release-plugin

I am using SVN and the Maven Release Plugin. When I try to apply a `release:prepare` I get the following error:

> svn: Commit failed
>
> (details follow):
>
> svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
>
> Valid Radar/Espresso number is not given with commit.

I know the Radar number. When I try to commit directly from the terminal the following command works:

> svn ci -m "rdar://34234242"

How do I pass the Radar number with the `release:prepare` command? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of dealing with this.  Both feel a bit hacky though.

**Option 1**

Set scmCommentPrefix to goal having it be your rdar number.

**Option 2**

Set suppressCommitBeforeTag in goal.  This would avoid the commit error but at the expense of not having the commit at all.